# Google Spreadsheet: Count column if criteria is met in the respective column and another column

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to COUNT the cells in column A if the cell in column A equals "X" and the adjacent cell in column B equals "January"?

Comment: If col A equals 'X' that would be a textual value. You can't sum text.. Do you want to count the number of occurrences of 'X' in col A AND 'January' in col B ?

Comment: My bad. Yeah, I want to know if there is a way to COUNT only the cells in Column A that equal "X" and have an adjacent cell in Column B that equals "January."

Comment: Then the first formula in my solution offered below, should work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In case you want to count the occurrences of 'X' (text) with 'January' in adjacent cell, try:

```
=countif(filter(A:A, B:B="January"), "X")
```

In case 'X' is actually a numeric value, and you want to sum all those numbers who have 'January' in the adjacent cell, try:

```
=sumif(B:B, "January", A:A)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do this programmatically using formulas, you could put the following in each cell on column C:

```
= IF ( B1 = "January" , A1 , 0 )
```

Then wherever you need the summed value to appear enter

```
= SUM(C1:C500)
```

Where 500 is the maximum number of rows you are enumerating.
You could also hide the "C" column if you wish.